# Scraping pdfs from this web

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape with python 2.7 from this website:

http://www.motogp.com/en/Results+Statistics/

I want to scrape the main one, that has many categories (Event), the one that appears next to the MotoGP Race Classification 2017 blue letters

And after that scrape for years as well. So far I have:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = "http://www.motogp.com/en/Results+Statistics/"
r  = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
type(soup)

match = re.search(b'\"(.*?\.pdf)\"', r)
pdf_url="http://resources.motogp.com/files/results/2017/ARG/MotoGP/RAC/Classification" + match.group(1).decode('utf8')
```

The links are this type:

```
http://resources.motogp.com/files/results/2017/AME/MotoGP/RAC/Classification.pdf?v1_ef0b514c
```

So I should add the thing "?" after the character. The main problem is how to switch from event to event to get all the links in this type of format.

Comment: If I'm not wrong then your only target is to get those `pdf` links connected to each event, right? If it is, you need to go for selenium or any browser simulator that can perform click because to make those `pdf` links visible it is necessary to initiate click on each events?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the description you have provided above, this is how can get those `pdf` links:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("http://www.motogp.com/en/Results+Statistics/")

for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#event option"))):
    item.click()
    elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "padleft5")))
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
    wait.until(EC.staleness_of(elem))

driver.quit()
```

Partial output:

```
http://resources.motogp.com/files/results/2017/VAL/MotoGP/RAC/worldstanding.pdf?v1_8dbea75c
http://resources.motogp.com/files/results/2017/QAT/MotoGP/RAC/Classification.pdf?v1_f6564614
http://resources.motogp.com/files/results/2017/ARG/MotoGP/RAC/Classification.pdf?v1_9107e18d
http://resources.motogp.com/files/results/2017/AME/MotoGP/RAC/Classification.pdf?v1_ef0b514c
http://resources.motogp.com/files/results/2017/SPA/MotoGP/RAC/Classification.pdf?v1_ba33b120
```

Comment: how can I add a loop for the years?
I am trying with: 
`for year in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#handle_season span"))):
 year.click()`

Comment: You should create another thread describing your current requirement and drop here a link to that post. I'll take a look. I'm working on a project at this moment. Thanks.

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288376/web-scrapping-with-a-double-loop-with-selenium-and-using-by-selector .