# Web scraping with a double loop with selenium and using By.SELECTOR

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get the pdf files from this website. I am trying to create a double loop so I can scroll over the years (Season) to get all the main pdf located in each year.

**The line of code is not working is this one. The problem is, I can not make this line work (The one that is supposed to loop all over the years (Season)**:

```
for year in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#season a aria-valuetext"))):
 year.click()
```

This is the full code:

```
  os.chdir("C:..")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get("http://www.motogp.com/en/Results+Statistics/")
    links = []


    for year in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#season a aria-valuetext"))):
     year.click()                                                          
     for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#event option"))):
         item.click()
         elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "padleft5")))
         print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
         links.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))
         wait.until(EC.staleness_of(elem))

    driver.quit()
```

This is a previous post where I got help with the code above:

[Scraping pdfs from this web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48269968/scraping-pdfs-from-this-web/48270910?noredirect=1#comment83555475_48270910)

Comment: What is the problem/question?

Comment: I updated the question with bold letters. My problem is, the first line of the for loop i.e. `for year in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#season a aria-valuetext"))):
 year.click()` is not working as I want it to work. I want to click all the seasons or years to get the pdfs that you can get of all the events for each year, the second line it does work: `for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#event option"))):`

Comment: "The line of code is not working is this one" is not a useful description. You should edit your post to include what you expect the code to do and what it actually does instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution below should work for you.  First, we iterate over the # of years in the CSS slider.  Then we work the list using your code example.  Added a sleep command because I kept getting a timeout.

**CODE**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("http://www.motogp.com/en/Results+Statistics/")

slider = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="handle_season"]')

for year in range(68):
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="event"]')))    
    for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#event option"))):
        item.click()
        elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "padleft5")))
        print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
        wait.until(EC.staleness_of(elem))

    slider.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT)
    time.sleep(1)


driver.quit()
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot of result]

Comment: @Shahin Nice catch, updated the post to include that import.  And thanks for the feedback.  :)

Answer (score 1):

If your working behind a firewall then a lot of times your EC’s won’t work. See if a time.sleep(10) function doesn’t get you past it, instead of an EC. Secondly, check the page_source before you run the EC... if you’re behind a firewall the HTML source code will tell you.